# Как передать тип компонента в GetComponent?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите как сохранить тип класса в перкменную и передать его в GetComponent?

Потому что у меня есть switch в котором все одинаково в каждой строке, только меняется тип в GetComponent в зависимости от другой переменной...

```
switch (myValue)
{
   case 1: myGameObject.GetComponent<Class1>().Do();
   break;
   case 2: myGameObject.GetComponent<Class2>().Do();
   break;
}
```

На самом деле там немного больше кода в каждом кейсе, но суть вопроса понятна... Как исправить подобное дублирование кода?

Пытался что то типо:

```
System.Type type = typeof(Class1);
myGameObject.GetComponent<type>().Do();
```

И все в таком духе

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) - `.GetComponent(typeof(HingeJoint))`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это использовать в моем случае

Comment: Вы же написали "Пытался что то типо", где использовали `typeof()`, только передавали его не туда, куда следует, я вам показал, как должно быть, а дальше уже подстраивайте под свою задачу.

Comment: Лучше свой код приложи, вместо этого примера. Хотя бы понятно будет что у тебя там дублируется.

Comment: А давайте не будем лечить код, который вы не показали?

Answer (score 1):

И как он по твоему будет исполнять метод класса, непонятно какого типа, у которого он не обязательно должен быть?

```
public interface IDoSomething 
{
    void DoSomething ();
}
```

---

```
public class FooA : Monobehaviour, IDoSomething 
{
    public void DoSomething ()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FooB : Monobehaviour, IDoSomething 
{
    public void DoSomething ()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Foo : Monobehaviour
{
    private IDoSomething[] _do;  
    private int _doIndex;

    public void Start () 
    {
        _do = new IDoSomething[2];
        _do[0] = GetComponent<FooA>();
        _do[1] = GetComponent<FooB>();
    }

    public void Do ()
    {
        _do[_doIndex].DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Либо через абстрактный класс.

Comment: А если допустим у меня есть класс родительский и все эти классы, тип которых я пытаюсь получить, они ему дочерние, в них всех реализован один и тот же метод, как то в этом случае можно сделать?

Comment: Я же написал, про наследование, абстрактный класс. Но ваще в таких случаях, когда кроме имени метода ниче общего, человеки пользуются интерфейсами.

Comment: Океюшки) время научиться пользоваться интерфейсами XD

Comment: Интерфейс это и есть хрен знает какой-то там `type`, но который точняк имеет метод `Do`. Ровно то что ты спросил.